# Create new jira issue from commit log

Tags: jira

Is it possible to configure jira in a way that you could use smart commit messages to automatically create a new issue? Lets say I'm committing a fix and would like to add a new issue directly just by annotating the commit log, would that be possible?

Comment: You can try enabling DVCS smart commits. But not entirely sure if this has been worked on before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading about [Smart Commits](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Using+smart+commits) which require Fisheye, it doesn't look like it. (Although there is at least 1 [Stash plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.lb.software.stash.smart.commit.lb-software-stash-smart-commit) that does it that doesn't require Fisheye)

If you're using Stash you can most likely create for example a [Asynchronous Post-receive Hook](https://developer.atlassian.com/stash/docs/latest/how-tos/repository-hooks.html) plugin that can watch the commit comments for like `#CreateIssue Resolved Bug` and then create within JIRA an issue with the Summary `Resolved Bug`.

Likewise if you're using GitHub you could use something that makes use of the [Web Hooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) functionality that takes in the event and then processes the commit comment and then uses the JIRA REST API to create the issue.

Likewise Bitbucket also has [Webhook Functionality](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Webhooks) and there are [plugins for Stash](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.stash.plugin.stash-web-post-receive-hooks-plugin) that do it as well.

Comment: Otherwise, the best way is to create a new issue through the browser? Can we close an issue using a commit message? What all things can be done through Jira smart commit?  Could you give some real-examples?